# Xero Api and bill status

Tags: xero-api

I'm using the Xero Api to create Invoices and Bills, however when I'm creating a new bills, I would like to have it authorised (awaiting payment), but when I add the status in XML `<Status>AUTHORISED</Status>`, it create the bill but as a draft.

I've tried to use `AUTHORISED` or `SUBMITTED` but it's not working.

Thanks,
Luo

Comment: Can you explain how it's not working? Whats the response status code? Any validation errors returned?

Comment: Hi, no error and the bill is created. It's just that it's created as a draft. I'm using a put request with cURL in php.
curl_error is empty
curl_result is null

Comment: I'm doing the same (albeit from vb, in JSON format, but apart from that...) and the invoices have "authorised" status when they get there. So in theory it works. Can you edit your question to show a complete XML structure?